# cannot pass two value to intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I want to pass two values to intent by using bundle, but the value is not passing when I click the intent. Below is the source code for this:

```
    public static final String ID_EXTRA = "com.example._ID";
    protected static final String ID_LISTID = "com.example._ID";
    String list = null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            list = getIntent().getStringExtra(main.ID_EXTRA);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productList);
   {
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            myid = (int) id;


        }

    });
}

==============================================================================
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(myid));
    bundle.putString(ID_LISTID, list);
    editProduct.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(editProduct);
```

Comment: What is `list` contains?

Comment: list = getIntent().getStringExtra(main.ID_EXTRA);
 list value , i get the value from main activity ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bundle` is built upon `HashMap`, using the same key in order to store value will cause last element you put to me replaced with the item you are inserting. Use different keys:

For instance:

```
 public static final String ID_EXTRA = "com.example._ID2";
 protected static final String ID_LISTID = "com.example._ID1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can answer this question without providing extra data:

- What is the value of ID_EXTRA.
- What is the value of ID_LISTID.

They should not be the same! You have supplied both the same values. Change this to something like "`com.example._ID1`" and "`com.example._ID2`".

- myid, is suspect this is an integer. Please add it via putInt list
- what is list? You say it is a string, but I don't really believe
  that. If it is, please rename your variable to something more understanding. Not only for you but also for the one who is going to use your code.